# Transfer CSV file using SCp and Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, scp

We have a task to transfer set of CSV files from win2003 server to unix server using SCP/Classic ASP. I don't have much idea about SCP and ASP combination. Could you please guide me how to transfer the file using SCP? If possible send me an sample script.

Answer (score 0):

ASP would need a COM object to do so. The easiest way would be to use [WScript.Shell.Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to run the command line scp. Needless to say it requires elevated privileges.